# How to remove duplicates in col1 and get group MAX in col2? / mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Given the following table:

```
col1 Col2
A    1
B    1
C    1
B    2
B    3
A    0
C    5
```

how do I write a SELECT query (I just assumed has to be SELECT) that returns the unique items of col1 and the max values of col2, like this:

```
A   1
B   3
C   5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) FROM mytable GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Indeed `SELECT  col1 , MAX(col2) FROM  mytable GROUP BY  col1` did the trick!